# Eclipse extension point for excluding faceted projects from XML validation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I develop an Eclipse plug-in which works on projects with certain facets. These projects are expected to have the validation builder enabled. However, when validation runs on XML files the XML validator complains about

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

which really isn't an issue in my situation, as I will implement a different validator for them.

I noticed that there is a global workspace preference which controls the defaults for the XML validator: Preferences -> Validation -> XML Validator -> Settings. My idea would be to contribute my project facet as an item for the default exclusion group, but I have no idea how to do that.

Any other suggestion on how to prevent XML validation from running on projects with a certain facet is of course welcome.

[image: Validation Filters for XML Validator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension point is `org.eclipse.wst.validation.exclude`, and is used as:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.validation.exclude">
    <validator id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xml">
        <exclude>
            <rules>
                <facet id="my.facet"/>
            </rules>
        </exclude>
    </validator>
</extension>
```